# Analysis of Moscow Mathematical Papyrus problem no. 10

Tags: geometry

This problem is giving me headaches for quite some time now I guess mainly because I am not a mathematician, but I would very much like to know if there is anyone here that has any deeper insight into this.

So, the Papyrus translation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Mathematical_Papyrus#Two_geometry_problems). Additionally there is a discussion presented [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086009000305) on whether the translation of the object in question is correct. They say it could possibly refer to the area of a semi-cylinder.

That said, I am wondering if anyone knows how could these ancient Egyptians have derived this algorithm? There is a fraction omnipresent throughout this algorithm (1/9). What could that fraction represent? Is there any way we could explain this algorithm intuitively? I guess we can 'assume' that they didn't know calculus, so how?

P.S. I have asked this question already on Stack Exchange, but without satisfying results.

**EDIT**

So to be more specific. The algorithm obviously works ignoring the small error compared to our current formula. They were very practical and didn't have sophisticated mathematical knowledge. So this is why I essentially want that whoever answers this forgets about our modern mathematics and thinks exclusively in the context of this algorithm and its operations to somehow make sense of this.

Comment: Again, as I asked on your question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401332/analysis-of-moscow-mathematical-papyrus-problem-no-10#comment1025701_401332): what was unsatisfactory about the answers you received on StackExchange?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Both the answers given were just explaining how the calculation compares to our modern form. I wish to know if there exists some sort of logic behind this. Like practically how could they have possibly arrived at this algorithm in the first place? It's in my question already basically, what does $1/9$ represent? Why take $1/9$ of remainders? What do all the little intermediary steps in this algorithm even represent in geometrical terms?

Comment: A similar algorithm is used to compute a circular area in the Rhind papyrus. The $256/81$ is used as the approximation for $π$ there too, hence the division by $9$. A common speculation, based on a drawing in the papyrus, is that they got it by approximating a circle by a regular octagon, see e.g. [Numberwarrior](https://numberwarrior.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/on-the-egyptian-value-for-pi/). The rest is their usual procedure for  calculations with [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction).

Comment: @Conifold I saw that before, but that concerns a circle and not a spherical 3D object. How did they arrive from this circle algorithm to the hemisphere algorithm?

Comment: @Conifold if you understand how that translates to a hemisphere algorithm then I would very much like to know how.

Comment: The latest discussion I could find in relevant literature indicates that (putting aside the question of whether it is dealing with a semi-sphere or a semi-cylinder) we do not know how the algorithm was derived: Leon Cooper, "Did Egyptian scribes have an algorithmic means for determining the circumference of a circle?", *Historia Mathematica*, Vol. 38, No. 4, Nov. 2011, pp. 455-484

Comment: @njuffa Didn't anyone ever even make an educated guess as to how it could have been derived? It seems strange that we are not capable of making some sort of logical sense of this even though it is just an approximation which is very very close to being correct.

Comment: @MichaelMunta If we assume Prob 10 is actually finding the area of a semicylinder (not a hemisphere), then the circle algorithm readily translates to the surface area problem. The scribe is using the formula $\frac{64}{81}*4d$ (d = diameter) to approximate the circumference of a circle.  From there, the area of the tubular portion of a whole cylinder would be the circumference times the height.  In Prob 10, d=4.5 so the circumference of a full cylinder is $\frac{64}{81}*4*4.5=14.2$  But we only need 1/2 the cylinder, so that's 7.1.  Then times the height of 4.5 yields 32, as in Prob 10.

Comment: Between Leon Cooper's essay (which you shared and is a great article!) and the Numberwarrior link @Conifold posted, that might be as close as we can get to answering your original question. From what I gather there, it seems plausible that Egyptians empirically determined a circle inscribed in a square is about 64/81 the area of the square, then they applied that to the circumference by saying it's the same fraction of the square's perimeter (4d). The 1/9 arises because the scribes are computing 8/9 of 8/9 ( = 64/81) of the perimeter.  Maybe I'll post an answer so I have more room...

Comment: @Brant this is still assuming a lot of things. Guess we will never know the way these people thought about those things...